# What does 'arm day' mean?

Tags: expressions

This one is a little bit of tricky because I do not have a context.

There's even a saying that says "Every day is arm day".

Does it mean workout day?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without context, that's the first thing I think of. *[Body part] day* is the day you target and work out your *[body part]*. On arm day, you work out your arms. They often say, "[Don't skip leg day.](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/skipping-leg-day)"

[image]

However, it could easily be something else that has to do with your arm, or [body part], with a particular context in mind.

Comment: Heh heh.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rNRw1pp-PR4

Answer (score 1):

*"Every day is [X] day"* is a well-known formula into which you can plug almost any activity that you consider so important you must do it every day.

Examples:

> - Every day is pizza day
> - Every day is a workout day

One particular case that's a common phrase:

> - Every day is a school day

This is a metaphor meaning the same as, "*You learn something new every day*."

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is that it could be short for “Armistice Day,” which is an older name for Veterans Day. Although this is not a standard abbreviation for this term, Veterans Day just occurred (November 11), so without any context, this is what I thought of when I read the quote.